# Enum doesn't understand what I want to set it to

Tags: python

this probably seems a little obvious to you, and I'm sure once I figure it out I will feel pretty beat up myself. But for the life of me, I can't figure out what's wrong. My teacher used this strip of code to explain how enum's work, but he never ran it, and when I run it, I keep getting back a weird result. Here is the entire code below:

```
from enum import Enum

class Shape(Enum):
    SQUARE = 2
    DIAMOND = 1
    CIRCLE = 3
    ALIAS_FOR_SQUARE = 2

if Shape.SQUARE == Shape.DIAMOND:
    print("SQUARE == DIAMOND")
else:
    print("SQUARE != DIAMOND")

if Shape.SQUARE == 2:
    print("SQUARE == 2")
else:
    print("SQUARE != 2")
```

After I run everything through, the prints are as follows

SQUARE != DIAMOND (Expected)

SQUARE != 2 (Unexpected)

For some reason, it says square isn't two when I've triple checked that it was set to 2, and I don't see anywhere else that it would have been altered

Answer (score 0):

`Shape.SQUARE` has type Shape while `2` has type `int` -- they are not equal. Do you want to use `Shape.SQUARE.value`?

```py
from enum import Enum

Shape = Enum("Shape", "DIAMOND SQUARE CIRCLE")
if Shape.SQUARE.value == 2:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failure")
```

Comment: Not how they are intended to be used.  The value is arbitrary, when it's not arbitrary an `IntEnum` should be used instead.  Otherwise: `if my_shape is Shape.SQUARE:`

Comment: Ok, so if I change it to [if Shape.SQUARE.value == 2] then that works? Just out of curiosity, what would shape.SQUARE be equal to? Is there a value that it holds, or is that only accessible through the value function?

Comment: Yes, it "works" but it's not really leading you in the right direction which is why I downvoted this code.  Enums use a metaclass which turns those class attributes into actual instances of the class, and you're supposed to just use those instances - not really care about their associated names or values.

Comment: @wim is correct on both counts. If you're exploring how enums work, then this code might be enlightening. If you're trying to use them for anything, don't compare their values to an integer -- use IntEnum which represents objects that _ARE_ that number (IntEnum is often used for bit flags, for instance)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that shape.SQUARE is not longer an int, so when comparing with an integer it will fail.

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>>
>>> class Shape(Enum):
...     SQUARE = 2
...     DIAMOND = 1
...     CIRCLE = 3
...     ALIAS_FOR_SQUARE = 2
...
>>> Shape.SQUARE
<Shape.SQUARE: 2>
>>> Shape.SQUARE == 2
False
>>> dir(Shape.SQUARE)
['__class__', '__doc__', '__module__', 'name', 'value']
>>> Shape.SQUARE.value == 2
True
>>> type(Shape.SQUARE)
<enum 'Shape'>
```

Enum is intended to create iterable objects, don't try to misuse as a const holder, no need for that.